# Using Sed to search for a string in an HTML file

Tags: macos, sed

I am going a simple sed search in an HTML file looking for the tag "title=":

`sed '/title=/ p' index.html`

I expect it to find that tag but sed prints the whole file.

I am using macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-n` to disable the default printing of every line:

```
sed -n '/title=/p' index.html
```

Or just use grep ;-)

Comment: Or `sed '/title=/!d' index.html`.